# How to fix the problem that putNextEntry(ZipEntry) does not accept ZipParameters?

Tags: java, zipoutputstream, zip4j

When I include `fileName` and `zipParameter` in `putNextEntry()`:

```
ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(fileName, zipParameter);
```

It shows an error:

```
The method putNextEntry(ZipEntry) in the type ZipOutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, ZipParameters).
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Show more related code. And a bigger stack trace if possible

Answer (score 1):

I hope your fileName wasn’t declared as String. It should be *FileOutputStream* as first argument, which should get *File*.

```
File zipFile = new File("file.txt");
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(zipFile));
try
{
 ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("myFile.txt"); // put file inside 
 zos.putNextEntry(entry);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
} finally
{
 zos.closeEntry();
 zos.close();
}
```

Try it , it may help

Comment: My fileName isn't declare as String. The problem I'm facing is I want to create a password protected zip, so I search it up online and what they do is that they included both file name and ZipParameters arguments in the putNextEntry() method like what I shown in my question above but it just couldn't work in my code.

Comment: @JonathanL. You went online where? And found what?

Comment: @JonathanL. java.util.zip library that has method putNextEntry for ZipOutputStream get only one parameter, which is ZipEntry.

Comment: Inside the link below is what I've found on how to create a password protected zip. The example three in the link below is what I'm doing now.

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=net.lingala.zip4j.io.ZipOutputStream

in the code in example 3. It includes both fileName and ZipParameters arguments, but when i do it this way, it doesn't work.

Comment: @JonathanL. That page is clearly labelled 'Java Code Examples for `net.lingala.zip4j.io.ZipOutputStream`'. Clearly that's not what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method signature of putNextEntry of java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream which accepts argument as `ZipEntry` only :

```
 /**
     * Begins writing a new ZIP file entry and positions the stream to the
     * start of the entry data. Closes the current entry if still active.
     * The default compression method will be used if no compression method
     * was specified for the entry, and the current time will be used if
     * the entry has no set modification time.
     * @param e the ZIP entry to be written
     * @exception ZipException if a ZIP format error has occurred
     * @exception IOException if an I/O error has occurred
     */

    public void putNextEntry(ZipEntry e) throws IOException {
        ensureOpen();
        if (current != null) {
            closeEntry();       // close previous entry
        }
       ....
```